# Problems When redirecting page with angularjs in IE9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I have the following script to redirect to the page I want

```
    $location.$$urlUpdatedByLocation = true;
    $location.$$absUrl = location.origin+location.pathname+"busqTerceros.html";
```

In the file busqTerceros.html I have the following:

```
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/cones/#!/search" />
```

This search is done from the AngularJS api router.
from what I've read in forums somehow IE loses the route when using #!

**Does anyone know why IE does this? How can it be solved?**

This works in Google chrome, Firefox, but not in IE, the error that was generated on the screen was the following:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrsDf.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. You're redirecting to a page that will immediately redirect you back to a different url? Why not load that url directly instead of taking a detour with the meta refresh. Also, if you're using angular, why not use the angular router to do all the redirecting? So could you please explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I am solving an issue of a system which was already working with this logic, but the problem of working with this logic is that in IE this redirect is not working, the idea is to try to solve the problem with the logic that already exists and if there is no solution I will have to do all this from the router.

Comment: I haven't seen a `<meta>` refresh since the 90's, so the app might be in need of a rewrite anyway. :) Have you tried relative paths? Or replacing the entire logic with `window.location.href` manipulation? Or serverside redirections?

Comment: try the redirection window.location.href and others derived from JS but the result is always the same an infinite loop.

Comment: I'm afraid I'll have to use the angular router to make this work.